# Proper syntax for jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I am currently working on a web app and am using jQuery.ajax() to pass some data from JavaScript to a python server. The call I am using is currently not working as expected and I would like confirmation that I am using it correctly. I read online that the call's syntax is `jQuery.ajax(url[, settings])` and I want to pass JSON data as the optional parameter so I am using the following:

```
jQuery.ajax("/login", JSON.stringify({Username: user, Password: pass}))
```

Should this pass that data in JSON form to that endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd parameter is expected to be a set of **key/value** pairs.

So

```
jQuery.ajax("/login", JSON.stringify({Username: user, Password: pass}))
```

should look something like

```
jQuery.ajax("/login", {
   data: JSON.stringify({Username: user, Password: pass})
});
```

Also it is is a better idea to use a common syntax all over the place, and I generally try to stick with

```
jQuery.ajax({
  // All the ajax settings
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will perform the serialisation for you so long as you pass the body of your request to the `data` property of the request's [settings object](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) (second parameter of `jQuery#ajax`):

```
jQuery.ajax("/login", {
    data: {
        Username: user,
        Password: pass
    }
});
```

Comment: note that the "serialisation" that jquery will do is different than sending the JSON that the op appears to be attempting.